# elasticsearch-dsl python count of unique values for a key

Tags: python-3.x, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

What I'm looking to do is a very simple query that just gets a count for the # of unique keys : an (account number)

```
search = Search(using=client, index=index_name).query(
         {
          "range": {
            "date": {
              "gte": "2021-08-01T08:00:00.000Z",
              "lte": "2021-08-31T23:59:59.599Z"
            }
        }
    })


#Make a query that checks how many account numbers (an) are in the index
search.sort({"count": {"order": "desc",  "mode" : "count"}})
search.aggs.bucket("an","cardinality",field="an")
es_data = search.execute()
print(es_data)
```

The results do not produce a count of unique `an` instead it just seems to be listing rows of data in the response.

What I expect it to respond with is something like this

`an: 100` for the 100 different account numbers that exist in the database

Answer (score 0):

Worked it out. Replaced:

```
search.sort({"count": {"order": "desc",  "mode" : "count"}})
search.aggs.bucket("an","cardinality",field="an")
es_data = search.execute()
```

With:

```
search.aggs.metric("by_cluster","cardinality",field="an")
es_data = search.execute()
pcc_count = es_data.aggregations.by_cluster.value
```

Now I get 1 metric returned with the unique count